# where are android style item attributes defined?

Tags: android, styles

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="colorWindowBackground">@color/Gray</item>
</style>
```

I wanted to add the property colorWindowBackground like so. Can I not just use any name I like? it seems like Android studio does not appreciate my behavior.

I'm guessing then that colorPrimary from item name is defined somewhere already. and that name can only be set to certain already existing properties.

how does the compiler know which properties are allowed? Is it somehow based on the parent the style is inherited from?

Comment: If you want to add, then add the custom name .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For using custom attributes in the views of layouts, you can use "declare-stylable" for custom names. Please follow below referred site :

https://guides.codepath.com/android/Defining-Custom-Views

Comment: this helped me understand how i can create my own, but i'm still confused as to where colorPrimary, colorAccent, and colorPrimaryDark are defined. They are not in my attrs.xml, so who defined these properties and where?

Answer (score 0):

@james Joshua, colorPrimary, colorAccent, and colorPrimaryDark are defined or in other words inherited from parent style Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar.

Comment: nvm figured it out after looking at https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/res/res/values/attrs.xml
and 
https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/core/res/res/values/themes.xml